# Split a string into tokens and subtokens

Tags: c

I need some help I have to write a code such that when user execute this

```
./a.out ’CSE/CSIT//EEE/EC//MECH//CIVIL:MBA:MBBS’  ’:’ ’/’
```

Output should be

```
Token 1 : CSE/CSIT//EEE/EC//MECH//CIVIL
Subtoken : CSE CSIT EEE EC MECH CIVIL
Token 2 : MBA
Subtoken : MBA
Token 3 : MBBS
Subtoken : MBBS
```

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

     char *str = strdup(argv[1]);
     char *delim = strdup(argv[2]);
     char *delim2 = strdup(argv[3]);

     char *token = strtok(str, delim);
     int i = 1;

     while(token != NULL){
         printf("\nToken %d : %s ",i,token);

         char *substr = strdup(token);
         // printf("\n %s",substr);
         
         char *subtoken = strtok(substr,delim2);
         printf("\nSubtoken :");
         while(subtoken != NULL){
             printf(" %s ",subtoken);
             subtoken = strtok(NULL, delim2);
         }
         
         token = strtok(NULL, delim); 
         i++;
     }
  
    return 0;
}
```

My Output:

```
Token 1 : CSE/CSIT//EEE/EC//MECH//CIVIL
Subtoken : CSE  CSIT  EEE  EC  MECH  CIVIL
```

Comment: `strtok` doesn't have the capability to keep track of more than one string. When you use it to extract the subtokens it forgets about the original string. You should use [strtok_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) instead.

Comment: Obligatory note: `strdup` is not standard C. It's standardized by POSIX though, so fine on Unix/Linux.

Comment: `strdup` works just fine on Windows too, you just have to ignore or disable the warning MSVC generates. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strdup-wcsdup?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot keep track of more than a single string with strtok(), you need to use [strtok_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r)

Comment: Use `strtok_r()` on POSIX systems and `strtok_s()` on Windows.  The signatures and behaviour match other than the last letter of the name.